# Split string by case insensitive word in java

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split a string by a word by ignoring the case of the word?
I have a string, say "This is a test split I like java". So I want to split this string based on the word "split" or "SPLIT". how can this be done?

Comment: How far have you come trying it yourself? Show us your code please...

Comment: See the answer that uses `Pattern.compile' in the duplicate.

Comment: Just do it str.split("split".toUppercase());

Comment: @flopcoder at which point "split" won't be taken into account any more.